# Paginate not working after sorting posts by views count

Tags: php, sorting

I want to show all posts in my website order by post views count highest to lowest.

I add below code to index.php

`<?
query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC');
?>`

I got correct result in only home page but when i view paginate pages there same posts repeat

Finally i want to order posts highest to lowest with paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is wordpress.

Did you see that your query string has no pagination information?
Try something like

```
...meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5')
```

Then be sure to [add the 'paged' key](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query).